# Join MS Teams meeting from my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, webview, microsoft-teams

I want to just provide a button in my flutter app. Upon clicking the button the user should be able to join the Teams meeting wither through the Teams app or through browser.

I am using a webview to launch teams as an URL in the in-app browser:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/1<meeting-id>",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But when I launch the URL, it gives an error in the webview:

```
Web page not available
The webpage at msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/<meeting-id> could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Any idea what's going wrong. Or any suggestions for any altrernate ways.

Answer (score -1):

You must not use

```
msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/<meeting>
```

as webview url but rather send and Intent with `ACTION_VIEW`. Even better, you should check if there's intent filter set for `msteams` scheme firstand then send the intent, otherwise use your webview and url with http/https scheme

Comment: But I am using the url as "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/1<meeting-id>" which seems a valid URL It starts with an "https" only

Comment: The problem with intenet is how do i launch Teams with an argument i,e, the meeting id?

Comment: Error message is clear - webview does not know what to do with `msteams` scheme

Comment: You use url as you have now but using intent lets android pass that to whatever app claims to handle msteams scheme - most likely mobile teams client app